# Como fazer um div preencher a largura restante com Css puro

Tags: css

tenho o seguinte codigo html:

```
<div class='pai'>
      <div class='filho1'>  Texto Qualquer que eu não sei o tamanho de caracteres </div>
      <div class='filho2'>  Componente que deve preencher a largura restante </div>
</div>
```

Preciso que '.filho1' tenha o seu tamanho de acordo com o seu conteúdo e que .filho2 preencha o espaço restante até atingir o limite da largura do '.pai'

Sei que as div .filho1 e .filho2 herdam as propriedades do pai portanto deixei o css da seguinte maneira

```
.pai{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.filho1{
    width: auto;
    background-color: red;
}
.filho2{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

porem quero que filho 2 tenha o tamanho de ( (100% de .pai) - (width de .filho1) )
e estou com dificuldades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá! aplique a propriedade "display:flex" na div pai, que permitirá a flexibilização do arranjo dos seu elementos filhos e na div que irá ficar com o restante do espaço do container a propriedade "flex-grow: 1", que fará com que ela "cresça" até ocupar o espaço total restante. Troquei a cor da classe filho2 para facilitar a visualização. Talvez no snippet não haja espaço suficiente para visualizar, coloque para abrir na tela toda. Mas pode copiar o css e testar que está correto.

```css
.pai {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.filho1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.filho2 {
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='pai'>
  <div class='filho1'> Texto Qualquer que eu não sei o tamanho de caracteres </div>
  <div class='filho2'> Componente que deve preencher a largura restante </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Desconhecia a propriedade flex, mas era exatamente isso que eu precisava, muito obrigado .

Comment: uma div pode ser um container flex e ao mesmo tempo um flex item ?

Comment: Pode sim. Dẽ uma lida neste link: https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/